# SwiftUI ObservedObject is re-initiated everytime

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uiviewrepresentable, environmentobject

I have a simple class to store some data in my SwiftUI app:

```
final class UserData: ObservableObject  {
    @Published var id = 1
    @Published var name = "Name"
    @Published var description = "Initial text"
}
```

I also defined it as `EnvironmentObject` in the main app struct:

```
ContentView(document: file.$document)
    .environmentObject(UserData())
```

In my Content View, I embedded a UIKit Text View:

```
EditorTextView(document: $document.text)
```

Where **EditorTextView** is a `UITextView` that is applied through `UIViewRepresentable`.

Now, what I'm trying to do is to update UserData within EditorTextView, like, storing some user input into `UserData.description`. So I defined the class inside my Coordinator as follows (the code is just for example):

```
class Coordinator: NSObject, UITextViewDelegate {
    @ObservedObject var userData = UserData()
    ...
    // Somewhere in the code, I update UserData when user taps Enter:
    func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
        if (textView.text.last == "\n") {
            userData.description = "My New Text"
        }
    }
```

**My problem is:**

Although it is updated with "My New Text" (as debugger shows), the value of `userData.description` is re-initiated again with the value "Initial text". It's like if UserData class is created everytime.

I tried to use @StateObject instead of @ObservedObject, but it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: You have to make up your mind, is it an environment object or an observed object?

Comment: It is environment object (to make it available to all views), but I used `@ObservedObject` in the uikit wrapper because I couldn't use `@EnvironmentObject` there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"It's like if UserData class is created everytime."

It is created everytime, right here:

```
class Coordinator: NSObject, UITextViewDelegate {
    @ObservedObject var userData = UserData()  // <--- here
```

Try this instead, and pass the UserData in from outside:

```
class Coordinator: NSObject, UITextViewDelegate {
    @ObservedObject var userData: UserData
```

Typically you would also do this in your main app struct:

```
@StateObject var userData = UserData()
...
ContentView(document: file.$document).environmentObject(userData)
```

Comment: Thanks, but how to initialize userData in the Coordinator init function?
    `init(_ parent: EditorTextView) {`
        `self.parent = parent`
    `}`

Comment: You have "@ObservedObject var userData: UserData" in the parent.
Then in Coordinator you have the init with the parent, then you can refer to it in Coordinator, 
like this: "self.parent.userData".

Comment: So I moved `@ObservedObject var userData: UserData` from the coordinator to the parent which is EditorTextView, but errors starts to appear. I've created a Minimal Reproducible Example, please take a look [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7ul8jpc8ixo693q/reprex.zip?dl=0)

Comment: I cannot download you code from that site. From my brief look at it:
it is clear to me that you need to read up on ObservedObject and EnvironmentObject,
how to use and pass them from one view to the next.

A simple how to use is at:  https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-use-environmentobject-to-share-data-between-views

In your ContentView you don't even have: "@EnvironmentObject var userData: UserData". 

My advice is, study a bit more on ObservedObject and EnvironmentObject.